# Combinations and permutations for my workplace

Tags: javascript

I am building a carriage calculator for my workplace, using HTML and Javascript, I have nearly completed it apart from a bit of styling. I am left with one Javascript part to complete, apart from using a lot of `if` and `else if`
statements I'm struggling.

We send pallets out using a carrier company, they designate prices by weight
Quarter pallet 250 kgs
Half pallet 500 kgs
Full pallet 1250 kgs
1 pallet space 1200 mm square

Anything less than 1200 mm long, easy, will be one pallet space
Anything over 1200 mm then the pallet spaces go up
e.g.
2000 mm would be 2 pallet spaces
3000 mm 3 pallet spaces etc.

Easy enough so far, the wall I am hitting is, if we send lengths which will use multiple spaces, finding the most efficient way of working out the best combination of pallet spaces.

e.g.
300 kgs, 3000 mm long, most efficient way, 3 quarter pallet spaces = 750 kgs maximum
800 kgs, 3000 mm long, most efficient way, 1 half pallet and 2 quarter pallet spaces = 1000 kgs maximum
and so on.

After thinking of ways to get the results I need this is what I have come up with so far, a big thank you to the stack overflow/exchange community (combine and compare functions), I will probably combine filteredResults & filteredWeights into an object and pull the information from that. I'm sure there are better ways of doing things but...

```
            var items = [
            { palletDef: 'Q', palletWeight: 250 },
            { palletDef: 'H', palletWeight: 500 },
            { palletDef: 'F', palletWeight: 1250 }
        ];
        var filteredResults = [];
        var filteredWeights = []
        var filterArray = [];
        var maxWeight = 1750; //-- Maximum weight forklift can carry --\\

        //Find all permutations
        Array.prototype.combine = function combine(k){
            var toCombine = this;
            var last;
            function combi(n, comb){
                var combs = [];
                for (var x=0, y=comb.length; x < y; x++){
                    for (var l = 0, m = toCombine.length; l < m; l++){
                        combs.push(comb[x] + toCombine[l]);           
                    }
                }
                if (n < k-1){
                    n++;
                    combi(n, combs);
                } else {
                    last = combs;
                }
            }
            combi(1, toCombine);
            return last;
        }

        // Sort permutations into unqiue combinations
        function compare(a,b) {
            var c = a.replace(/\W+/g, '').toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("");
            var d = b.replace(/\W+/g, '').toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("");
            return (c === d) ? d.toUpperCase() : 0;
        }

        function getWeight(key) {
            for ( var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++){
                if(items[i].palletDef == key) return items[i].palletWeight;
            }
        }

        // Find combinations of pallets
        function findCombinations(pallets) {

            var toCombine = [];
            for ( var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
                toCombine.push(items[i].palletDef);
            }

            //Get all permutations
            var results = pallets > 1 ? toCombine.combine(pallets) : toCombine;

            //Remove duplicate items
            for (var i = 0, l = results.length; i < l; i++){
                if(compare(results[i], results[i]) !=0) {
                    if(filterArray.length == 0) {
                        filterArray.push(results[i]); filteredResults.push(results[i]);
                    } else if(filterArray.indexOf(compare(results[i], results[i])) == -1) {
                        filterArray.push(compare(results[i], results[i]));
                        filteredResults.push(results[i]);
                    }
                }
            }

            //Add up results
            for (var i = 0, l = filteredResults.length; i < l; i++){
                var palletsWeight = 0;
                for (var a = 0, len = filteredResults[i].length; a < len; a++){
                    palletsWeight += getWeight(filteredResults[i].charAt(a));
                }
                filteredWeights.push(palletsWeight);
            }

            //Trim weights (for forklift)
            for (var i = filteredWeights.length; i--;){
                if(filteredWeights[i] > maxWeight) {
                    filteredResults.splice(i, 1);
                    filteredWeights.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
            return filteredResults +""+ filteredWeights;                
        }


console.log(findCombinations(3));
```

Comment: Sounds like a packing problem.

Comment: Without seeing the current calculation source code it's impossible to tell you why it isn't working or to offer a solution. Please update your question with the relevant source code. If you can give us a working example of the data being calculated someone might be able to fix the undefined||null issue.

Comment: @m6nut, you may ask such questions at this site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @kelin as explained in the [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), codereview is for reviews of *existing, working* code. This question is definitely off-topic there.

Comment: @kelin assuming there's actual working code to be reviewed, yes. In its current form, this question would be closed in nanoseconds on Code Review.

Comment: Thanks @kelin and Mat's Mug I'll try you suggestions, the code I have working is very rudimentry and as I say just relies on if statements

Comment: Oops, I meant this site: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @kelin - algorithm questions are on-topic for Programmers, but "make an algorithm for me" is not.  It's equally off-topic for here and Programmers.  See also: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7182/what-goes-on-programmers-se-a-guide-for-stack-overflow

Comment: @GlenH7, sorry if I've caused any offence, I did not want  an algorithm made just some pointers. I have had a few days off and come at it with fresh eyes and I'm making some progress. Thank you for your suggestions.